# How to perform custom segue from one view controller to another instance of the same view controller?

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

How can I perform a custom segue from one instance of a view controller to another instance of the same view controller?

For starters, I just tried to implement a custom segue from one vc to a different vc. This was successful, and I did it as follows.

1. I subclassed UIStoryboardSegue to create a custom segue.

```
class MyCustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        // Custom transition stuff here.
    }
```

2. In my storyboard, I created a segue from one vc to another one, and changed the class to `MyCustomSegue`, and gave it an identifier "MyCustomSegueID".
3. I successfully implemented the segue programmatically by calling `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyCustomSegueID", sender: self)`. Note: The segue needs to be performed programmatically because certain things are variable.

Next, I tried to perform the same custom segue transition from an instance of one view controller to another instance of the same view controller, but I was unable to do so. I have a couple of confusions regarding this:

1. I can't (or haven't figured out how to...) create a segue in the storyboard from one vc to the same vc (like I did in the first part where I created a segue from one vc to a different vc).
2. I thought I might need to override the `init` in my custom segue class so that I could edit the `source` and `destination` values, since in the Apple Developer Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue), it says the following.

> If you need to initialize any variables in your custom segue subclass, you can also override the init(identifier:source:destination:) method and initialize them in your custom implementation.

But I'm not really sure how to do that or how it would help.

So, does anyone know how I can do what I'm trying to accomplish?